# Run observables in parallel without knowing the number of them until runtime

Tags: rx-java

When I want to run several observables in parallel and I know which ones, I use `combineLatest()`. I am looking for an elegant recipe on how to run multiple observables in parallel but without knowing which and how many observables until runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This version of `combineLatest` would work, no?

```java
public static <T,R> Observable<R> combineLatest(java.lang.Iterable<? extends Observable<? extends T>> sources,
                            FuncN<? extends R> combineFunction)
```

You pass it a collection of Observables, and supply a `FuncN` which takes a varargs argument list.

Comment: Ha! Thanks. I missed that function from the documentation.